# Optimize nested for loop for calculating xcorr of matrix rows

Tags: matlab, performance, optimization, vectorization, bsxfun

I have 2 nested loops which do the following:

- Get two rows of a matrix
- Check if indices meet a condition or not
- If they do: calculate xcorr between the two rows and put it into new vector
- Find the index of the maximum value of sub vector and replace element of `LAG` matrix with this value

I dont know how I can speed this code up by vectorizing or otherwise.

```
b=size(data,1);
F=size(data,2);
LAG= zeros(b,b);  

for i=1:b
    for j=1:b
        if j>i
            x=data(i,:);
            y=data(j,:);
            d=xcorr(x,y);
            d=d(:,F:(2*F)-1); 
            [M,I] = max(d);
            LAG(i,j)=I-1;
            d=xcorr(y,x);
            d=d(:,F:(2*F)-1);
            [M,I] = max(d);
            LAG(j,i)=I-1;
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

### First, a note on floating point precision...

You mention in a comment that your data contains the integers 0, 1, and 2. You would therefore expect a [cross-correlation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr.html#bubr0h6) to give integer results. However, since the calculation is being done in [double-precision](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html), there appears to be some [floating-point error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/686439/52738) introduced. This error can cause the results to be ever so slightly larger or smaller than integer values.

Since your calculations involve looking for the location of the [maxima](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html), then you could get slightly different results if there are repeated maximal integer values with added precision errors. For example, let's say you expect the value 10 to be the maximum and appear in indices 2 and 4 of a vector `d`. You might calculate `d` one way and get `d(2) = 10` and `d(4) = 10.00000000000001`, with some added precision error. The maximum would therefore be located in index 4. If you use a different method to calculate `d`, you might get `d(2) = 10` and `d(4) = 9.99999999999999`, with the error going in the opposite direction, causing the maximum to be located in index 2.

The solution? [Round](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/round.html) your cross-correlation data first:

```
d = round(xcorr(x, y));
```

This will eliminate the floating-point errors and give you the integer results you expect.

Now, on to the actual solutions...

### Solution 1: Non-loop option

You can pass a matrix to [`xcorr`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr.html) and it will perform the cross-correlation for every pairwise combination of columns. Using this, you can forego your loops altogether like so:

```
d = round(xcorr(data.'));
[~, I] = max(d(F:(2*F)-1,:), [], 1);
LAG = reshape(I-1, b, b).';
```

### Solution 2: Improved loop option

There are limits to how large `data` can be for the above solution, since it will produce large intermediate and output variables that can exceed the [maximum array size available](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/memory.html). In such a case for loops may be unavoidable, but you can improve upon the for-loop solution above. Specifically, you can compute the cross-correlation once for a pair `(x, y)`, then just flip the result for the pair `(y, x)`:

```
% Loop over rows:
for row = 1:b

  % Loop over upper matrix triangle:
  for col = (row+1):b

    % Cross-correlation for upper triangle:
    d = round(xcorr(data(row, :), data(col, :)));
    [~, I] = max(d(:, F:(2*F)-1));
    LAG(row, col) = I-1;

    % Cross-correlation for lower triangle:
    d = fliplr(d);
    [~, I] = max(d(:, F:(2*F)-1));
    LAG(col, row) = I-1;

  end

end
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your care:)
I use this now ,but I got this error('Error using bsxfun
Requested 1024x4000x4000 (244.1GB) array exceeds maximum array size
preference. Creation of arrays greater than this limit may take a long time
and cause MATLAB to become unresponsive. See array size limit or preference
panel for more information.')

Comment: @FaribaJangjoo: I'm guessing `data` is 4000-by-1024? That apparently produces intermediate and output variables (like `d`) that are too big. Given the size of your problem, you may be limited to using loops to save on memory. However, there are improvements you can make to your loop. I'll update shortly.

Comment: my main matrix is 2500*412000. but I run it for 4000*400 now to check it and it gives me this error.

Comment: I checked my previous result with this one ,but It doesn't give me the same result as before, :(

Comment: @FaribaJangjoo: Try now. I removed the auto-correlation part since you aren't performing those in your code.

Comment: it still gives me wrong result,i think in your code it doesn't consider whole rows ,I don't know if I understand it right or not...

Comment: @FaribaJangjoo: I'm getting matching results when I test the solutions with random data. I tried to speed it up by computing a single cross-correlation, then just flipping that result for the cross-correlation with flipped inputs. This *should* give the same result, so I don't know where the error is coming from.

Comment: hmm:(...would you mind checking it again for another matrix?
ireally need this to work...sorry for interrupting you

Comment: @FaribaJangjoo: I've already tested it on half a dozen random matrices and gotten matching results. Are you redefining `b` and `F` for each new matrix you test?

Comment: I put these  3lines once above your code (b=size(data,1);
F=size(data,2);LAG= zeros(b,b);)...should I do anything else?

Comment: i changed this line(d = fliplr(d);)with( d = xcorr(data(col, :), data(row, :));)  & it gives the same results..is it ok?but its so much slower than my original code :(

Comment: @FaribaJangjoo: Changing that line should give you something nearly identical to your original code. What sort of data do you have?

Comment: @FaribaJangjoo: It turns out the reason the solutions were giving different results is due to floating-point precision error, which I describe above. You have to round the cross-correlation results in your solution to avoid this.

Comment: thanks a lot for helping me but,i use edited form ,but it still gives me a different result from what i want...

Comment: @FaribaJangjoo: If "what you want" is what is in the question, then what you want isn't quite right. Note that, as I discuss above, you would need to round the results you get from `xcorr` in your solution to remove floating-point errors. The results should match after you do that.